Solid of Revolution of $y=\ln(x), y=1, y=2, x=0$ about the $y$-axis. Did I do something wrong?
I'm trying to calculate the volume defined by rotating $y=\ln(x), y=1, y=2, x=0$ about the $y$-axis.
Although I did my calculations, I just have doubts on it and I need someone to check my work,
My integral setup is
$$V=\int_{1}^{2}\pi e^{2y} \ dy$$
Making the substitution $u=2y$,
$$V=\int_{2}^{4}\pi \frac{e^{u}}{2} \ du=\frac{\pi}{2}(e^{4}-e^{2})\approx 74,1558$$
Is there any mistakes I made? And also how would the integral setup would look like if I instead used the Cylindrical Shells Method?

I found the same $V$ by shell method after some mistakes. I think your solution is ok.

If we were to use the cylindrical shells method, we would have an inner solid cylinder with volume:
$$\pi \times e^2 \times 1 = \pi e^2$$
And then for the region with $e \le |x| \le e^2$, we integrate cylindrical shells with variable height to get:
$$\int_{x=e}^{x=e^2} 2\pi x(2-\ln{x})dx$$
$$=\left[2\pi x^2 - 2\pi \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln{x}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right]_{x=e}^{x=e^2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi e^4}{2}-\frac{3 \pi e^2}{2}$$
Adding the two volumes we get:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}(e^4-e^2) \approx 74.1558$$
Which verifies your answer

Ah I see, so when using the cylindrical shells we only integrate from $e$ to $e^{2}$ but that leaves a 'hole' in the center which is a cylinder of volume $\pi e^{2}$.

@JAB Yes, precisely
